# How to Prove That Branch Points Of $\log (f(z))$ are Zeros and Poles of $f(z)$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, branch-cuts, branch-points

In many books and notes, It is written that the branch points of $\log (f(z))$ are points $z\in \Bbb C$ such that $f(z)=0$ or $z$ is a pole of $f$. Here we assuming that zero of $f$ is the sense of analytic functions. I am wondering how to prove this. Any help would be appreciated. Also, are there related theorems to find branch points of arbitrary complex functions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If $f(z)=\frac{1}{\sqrt z}$ then $z=0$ is a brach point (not a zero or a pole) and $\log f(z)$ has a brach point at $z=0$. You have to take into account other possible singularities of $f$ not just poles. Also, note that if $\log f(z)$ is holomorphic at $z$ then $(\log f(z))' = \frac{{f'(z)}}{{f(z)}}$.

Comment: @Gary, at least, can you tell me how can I prove that $\log(f(z))$ has a branch point at $z$ when $f(z)=0$?

Comment: Suppose that $f$ has a zero at $z_0$ an is analytic at $z_0$. Then $$
f(z) = a(z - z_0 )^m \left( {1 + a_1 (z - z_0 ) + a_2 (z - z_0 )^2  +  \cdots } \right)
$$ in a neighbourhood of $z_0$ with some positive integer $m$. Thus \begin{align*}
\log f(z) & = \log a + m \log (z - z_0 ) + \log \left( {1 + a_1 (z - z_0 ) + a_2 (z - z_0 )^2  +  \cdots } \right) \\ &  = m \log (z - z_0 ) + \log a + a_1 (z - z_0 ) + \left( {a_2  - \frac{{a_1 }}{2}} \right)(z - z_0 )^2  +  \cdots 
\end{align*} in a suitable neighbourhood of $z_0$. You can see that $\log f(z)$ has a logarithmic brach point at $z=z_0$.

Comment: Thanks! I got it. But can give me tell me about some resources where I can find techniques and tricks to find branch points of arbitrary complex functions?